# How can I improve this SQL query performace?

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

I have this query as shown below. I did "EXPLAIN ANALYZE" on the query to see bottlenecks in the query performance and the JOINS were the culprit.

I have a brief description of table structures to give better idea. The tables itself can't be changed.

```
table ai {
   a_id foreign_key
   i_id foreign_key
} 
table a {
   id
   c_id foreign_key
}
table i {
   id
   value
}
table c {
   name
   begin_time
   id
}
```

Here is the SQL query.

```sql
SELECT
  DISTINCT ON (c.begin_time, c.id)
  c.id,
  c.name,
  c.begin_time
FROM
  ai
  INNER JOIN i ON (
    ai.i_id = i.id
  )
  INNER JOIN a ON (
    ai.a_id = a.id
  )
  INNER JOIN container ON (
    a.c_id = c.id
  )
WHERE
  i.value = 'a.b.c.d'
ORDER BY
  c.begin_time DESC
```

I am not expert in SQL querying. I wanted to know if the query itself can be changed for performance improvement.

Comment: You should add Primary keys + foreign keys to your tables (and maybe some extra indexes) Also: there are no `{}` in DDL.

Comment: And you don't need the DISTINCT, you are only select from `c`. Use `EXISTS(...)` in the where clause.

Comment: I'm confused. Is `c.id` a primary key or not?  If so, why do you need the begin time?

Comment: Without the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, BUFFERS) from your query, it's almost impossible to see what the problem is. You could simplify the query, but that doesn't mean the query becomes fast. Maybe you're missing some crucial indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- your main query only needs the `c` table
- , the other tables are only needed to determine if a `c`record is wanted in the final result
- (if) the `c` table does not contain duplicates: the DISTINCT is not needed anymore.

Simplified query:

---

```
SELECT
  c.id, c.name, c.begin_time
FROM c
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM ai
        JOIN i ON ai.i_id = i.id AND i.value = 'a.b.c.d'
        JOIN a ON ai.a_id = a.id
        WHERE  a.c_id = c.id
        )
ORDER BY c.begin_time DESC
        ;
```

Comment: "WHERE  ai.c_id = c.id" fails because the table "ai" doesn't have the foreign key "c_id". It is only present in table "a" .

Comment: I had to guess. Please add the complete DDL for your tables to the question (next time)

Comment: The query works! I just had to make minor change. Thanks a ton.